# Links don't work in col-xs on one page

Tags: javascript

I have a site that on one page uses the DOM and thus JavaScript to transfer text to it. There is a sidebar with id pastEvents given a width of col-xs-3 and a main section with and id = eventsReports and a width of col-xs-9.  The design of the page is bog standard: Menu under which is the logo then under that is a sidebar to the left with the main display area on its right and under it a footer.

The problem is that the links from the sidebar, while operating perfectly on a larger screen, don't work in the xs mode, neither when shrinking the screen on my desktop using any number of browsers with their developer counterparts nor on my mobile.

The links from the sidebar are like this:

```
<li class="rpts" onclick="fn2016(x=7)"><a href="#">Tea 'n Talk - Marine Life on the Eurobodalla and Local Coast</a> (25/03/17) </li><br>
```

The JavaScript is thus:

```
<script>
    var x; //integer received from the onclick event passing the report number

    function fn2016(x) {

        var request;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

             request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        } else {

             request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

        }

        request.open('GET', 'eventReports/rpt_' + x + '.html');

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if ((request.readyState===4) && (request.status===200)) {

           var modify = document.getElementById('eventsReports');

           modify.innerHTML = request.responseText;

           }

           }

           request.send();

           }

</script>
```

The receiving part's html is:

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" id="eventsReports">

</div>
```

This works a treat on all devices but the smallest in which even the links don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem.  It had nothing to do with JavaScript or Ajax.  Thanks to all who have looked at this

Comment: May I suggest removing the question then, it's just noise now

Comment: Love to.  Only problem is that I can't find how to.

Comment: There should be a close this question link or something similar